# wrong email -address- in mailq, Why doesn't the sender be notified?

Tags: postfix

I use postfix relay smtp server.
Rarely send senders to a faulty email address but not send a notification to the sender that the address is wrong, only the letter is in the mail queue.

766AA2133F    46933 Sat Jan 12 19:44:40  from@nobody.tr
          (connect to mail.somebody.tr[203.188.141.10]:25: No route to host)
                             wrong-email-address@wrong-domain.tr

Why doesn't the sender be notified?
which postfix to use for the solution ?
thanks,
Steven

Comment: This message is still queued because the problem described in the log entry is temporary, and it might succeed to contact the remote mail server later. You'll need to wait until Postfix gives up (usually 5 days) or reaches the remote mail server and fails to deliver the mail before it will notify the sender of failure.

Comment: The email address is wrong, and 5 days is too much. What can be reduced?

Comment: Funny you should ask, I've written on this topic before. You can read it at [Is it a good idea to reduce the give-up time for e-mail delivery?](https://serverfault.com/q/735269/126632) (which also contains a workaround that may help you).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

maximal_queue_lifetime (default: 5d) Consider a message as undeliverable, when delivery fails with a temporary error, and the time in the queue has reached the maximal_queue_lifetime limit. Time units: s (seconds), m (minutes), h (hours), d (days), w (weeks). The default time unit is d (days). Specify 0 when mail delivery should be tried only once.

Resolution:

postconf -e 'maximal_queue_lifetime = 1d'

thanks for the help, by